# Reading email from database without @ or

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to recall data from database to post later on 
When someone logs in using this code:

```
    function login($email, $password, $mysqli)
    {
        // Using prepared statements means that SQL injection is not possible. 
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, username, password, salt, phnumber, realname, age, sex FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {

            $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);  // Bind "$email" to parameter.
            $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            // get variables from result.
            $stmt->bind_result($user_id, $username, $db_password, $salt, $phnumber, $realname, $age, $sex);
            $stmt->fetch();
             }
     }
```

Then I set variables for email and name using this code:

```
$realname = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+/", "", $realname);        
$_SESSION['realname'] = $realname;
$email = preg_replace("/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/", "", $email);        
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
```

Then when I recall all the variables using `print_r($_SESSION);` The email is posted without @ or . for example: `johnsmithyahoocom` and also the name is posted without space like `JohnSmith` Which is undesirable.
 How can I make it post the right email form and space between names?

Comment: you should validate your input before you put the info in your database, and not on the way out

Comment: @zedd It's validated with Javascript before it's entered and in the database it's `johnsmith@yahoo.com` I just can't recall it like that, it's posted without @ or . and name is posted without spaces.

Comment: If that regex is used to "sanitize" the email address, then you have got a hole bunch of issue there... It never really is a good idea to try to be smarter than the users and "fix" their input. You will fail. For example TLDs can have more than 4 characters and a domain can have more than two labels...

Comment: It's used to validate the email address form, the value in the database is posted correctly, nothing wrong. I just can't call it in the correct form.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using preg_replace?

And I would recommend, if you are already using a database, to store only the users ID in the SESSION and fetch the other data from the database, when you need the users Information.

Comment: I'm using pref_replace as XSS protection. Even I remove it, it's still the same doesn't post @, "." or spaces.

Comment: Use PHPs function [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php) for XSS Protection. Are the values in the database correct? If not the Problem lies before you call the login function. You must have already filtered out the @ and "." before you saved the values in the database

Comment: I use `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities` when I recall data. But that still didn't post the right email form or spaces.

Comment: The values in the database are correct. I just can't call in the right form. @иikolai

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time on this 
Everything was going fine I just had to relogin to apply changes I made

`/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b/` is working fine and recalls the right email form from database I just had to restart the `SESSION` to see changed I made.